# TypeError: VideoWriter() missing required argument 'frameSize' (pos 5) with opencv-python ==4.4.0.42

Tags: video-capture, opencv, python

I want to create VideoWriter with the following code:

```
  fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

  video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('out.mp4',fourcc,fps,(frame_width,frame_height))
```

but i get the error:

```
   TypeError: VideoWriter() missing required argument 'frameSize' (pos 5)
```

when i change my code to:

```
   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

   video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(filename='out.mp4',fourcc=fourcc,fps=fps,frameSize=(frame_width,frame_height))
```

i get another error:

```
   TypeError: VideoWriter() missing required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2)
```

so i change my code to :

```
   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

   video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(filename='out.mp4',apiPreference=0,fourcc=fourcc,fps=fps,frameSize=(frame_width,frame_height))
```

i get error:

```
   TypeError: VideoWriter() missing required argument 'params' (pos 6)
```

How could i solve it? Could anyone tell me how to use the api:VideoWriter()?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

ok, the following code works for me :

```
frame_num = int(Cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
frame_width = int(Cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(Cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(result,fourcc,fps,(frame_width,frame_height))
```

the type of Cap.get(cv2.*) is float, so i change it to integer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works. Others who are reading this answer please make sure that you convert the num, width, height to int before using.

Comment: I have the same problem but this does not work for me. I have tried multiple ways to convert the resolution size to integers but it still does not work. Is there any other way? Should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 1):

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(path,apiPreference = 0,fourcc = fourcc, fps = 30,frameSize = (256,256) )
 
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    out.write((img_as_ubyte(predictions[i])))
out.release()
```

it did worked for me
used skimage's image_as_ubyte to convert float to int.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out I was passing a `pathlib.Path` instead of a string for the filename. Converting to string helped. Seems openCV is not very good with reporting that it received the wrong types. So make sure you check all types of the arguments you are passing.